# How to render an Icon x amount of times - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm pretty new to dart/flutter so apologies if this is an obvious solution but I'm trying to render an Icon for a dynamic amount of times based on a models property.

I'm trying something like this:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
     _starsForRatings()
    ],
  )

List<Icon>_starsForRatings() {
  List<Icon> stars = [];
  for(int i = 0; i < _rating; i++){
    stars.add(Icon(Icons.star));
  }
 return stars;
}
```

But I'm getting the error 'The element type List can't be assigned to the list type Widget' which makes sense, however I can't think of another way to render it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.
The problem is that you are packing a List into another List.
What I mean is that `_starsForRatings()` is already returning the list you need. You don't need to put that List into another one before assigning it to the `children` property of the Row.
Try this instead:

```
Row(
  children: _starsForRatings(),
)

List<Icon>_starsForRatings() {
  List<Icon> stars = [];
  for(int i = 0; i < _rating; i++){
    stars.add(Icon(Icons.star));
  }
  return stars;
}
```

Comment: If this works you may want to accept answer as it solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, I just had to wait for 10mins to pass before accepting it